# Python - proper way of importing sub-modules with dependencies using __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I was trying to pack a few functionalities (`module_1`, `module_2`, ...) into one big package (`MyProject`) using `__init__.py` files. The problem is, I am unable to use a function with dependencies (imported functions from other python scripts inside the same folder).
Here's an example of my catalogues structure:

```
+MyProject
|-__init__.py
|-run_everything.py
|
|-+ module_1
| |-__init__.py
| |-run_module.py
| |-script_1.py
| |-script_2.py
|
|-+ module_2
| |-....
|
|-+ module_3
| |-....
```

`run_module.py` imports only functions from `script_1.py`, `script_2.py` in the same directory/module.

As long as I run `run_module.py` from each `module_1, 2,...` separately they work fine. However, if I try to import 'run_module' into `run_everything.py`, I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError` from modules imported inside the sub-module.

I've looked through the stack (and not only) and as I understand I should use one of the following methods, which in my case don't work:

1.

`__init__.py` inside `module_1`:

```
import script_1
import script_2
```

Imports inside `run_everything.py`:

```
import module_1
import module_2
...
```

I'm getting:

```
import script_1.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script_1.py'
```

From what I understand explicitly importing all of scripts inside `__init__.py` in module_1 should make them available, so why the error?

2.
The same error occurs if I use clean `__init__.py` file, but add dot notation into my `run_everything.py` file:

```
import module_1.script_1
import module_1.script_2
...
```

I understand that this should also import everything that's imported inside script_1, script_2...?

3.
I was also trying to use:

```
from module_1.run_module import function()
```

with the same error, but since it depends on the other functions that's not surprising.

---

What I want to achieve is to use a function start() from `run_module.py` like this:

```
import module_1
...
module_1.run_module.start()
```

This function is using other functions from `script_1`, `script_2` inside the same folder.

I know that I could do the imports through os paths, but since `__init__.py` exists, I'd like to use it.

Comment: "I know that I could do the imports through os paths" you should *never* do that.

Comment: Anyway, the solution is to actually package your project then install it. Here is a basic intro on how to do that: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Note, you don't have to upload to the Python Package Index, that is only if you *want* to share your code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure it it actually answers my question. I'm trying to use a function within a package, not outside of it. Does it mean that I can't use __init__.py for importing files without installing a package?

Comment: This is the way you *should be doing this*. What you have *isn't really a package* until you *package it*. And solving the issues of importing it is precisely what *installing* it does. This is the *normal way* that you would work with any project.

Comment: The important thing is how your import path is going to *actually find things*. You seem to assume that imports are inherently relative, so when you are in `module1` then `import script_1` should work. It won't (not unless you package it that way), but normally given your layout, it would have to be (depending on your working direcdtory or which directory you manually add to the PYTHONPATH) `import module1.script1`

Comment: Although, really, given that you have an `__init__` inside of `MyProject`, then it would be `import MyProject.module1.script1`, again, this depends on what exactly is in your import path. If you don't actually package and install your project, then *you have to manually handle the PYTHONPATH somehow*, even if it is cd'ing into a convenient working directory (because the working directory that was used when you invoke python will automatically be added to the import path).

Comment: But that isn't what you want to do, you want to package your project, then install it, probably using an editable install if you want to be actively developing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need import the functions from script_1 and script_2 to `run_module.py` with a point

Example

```py
# run_module.py

from .script_1 import func1
from .script_2 import func2


def start ():
    func1()
    func2()
```

Then in `__init__.py` inside `module_1`:

```py
# __init__.py
from .run_module import start
```

Finally in `run_everything.py` :

```py
# run_everything.py
from module_1 import start

start()
```

And:

```
python3 run_everything.py
```